# Chain-signing elements of an Akka Stream

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have a `Source[ByteString]` that needs to be transformed in the following manner:

- Each `ByteString` element needs to have a cryptographic signature concatenated to it.
- The signature to be concatenated to the first element in the stream is known beforehand.
- Each signature after that is computed from the data in the preceding element (the unsigned version), then concatenated to its corresponding element.

The desired result is conceptually a `Source` of data chunks that are chained together via signatures. The overall functional signature would be `(Source[ByteString]) => Source[ByteString]`. Almost like a `map()` but computationally tying later elements to their predecessors.

I had hoped to use `Source.fold()` to achieve this, but I can't find the right `zero` that will let me carry signatures into each iteration of the fold, but also emit the signed chunks as if the stream had simply been mapped over.

(Concretely, I'm trying to implement the AWS S3 algorithm for signing a chunked object upload, as documented at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-streaming.html#sigv4-chunked-body-definition.)

What's a good approach to take here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there with your idea to use `fold` here - you need `scan` which is essentially the same but keeps the stream of transformed elements, and passes the result to the next iteration.

So, given you have a method `def sign(prevElement: ByteString, thisElement: ByteString): ByteString`, your flow can be described as follows:

```
Flow[String]
  .scan(zeroSignature)(sign)
  .drop(1)
```

`scan` keeps zero element which you probably don't need, so `drop(1)` is needed to discard it.

Comment: `scan` was indeed exactly what I needed. I set the zero to the tuple `(zeroSignature, ByteString.empty)`, and after the `scan` just did `.map(_._2).filterNot(_.isEmpty)` to remove the zeroth `ByteString`. Thanks for helping me over the mental hurdle!